# Bootstrap Modal - toggling modal with an anchor with a valid external HREF (for backup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

The reason for this to cover any user that MAY have javascript turned off. It's a company standard that we develop our web pages for this, since our demographic still have their VCR's blinking 12:00.

I have a text link that is being populated by a database call:

```
<a href="article.html?aID=123" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#theModal" data-aid="123">Click for Article</a>
```

The common user experience is that the user will click the link, and it will toggle a modal displaying the article. BUT we want to incorporate a fallback in case the user has javascript turned off, so when the link is clicked, it will simply take the user to the article page and display the dynamic content loaded by padding the Article ID of 123.

Currently with Bootstrap properly loaded on the page, when the user clickson the link, it just goes to the article page and does NOT toggle the modal.

What method do I need to add to a onClick event to prevent this click through from occuring, but still toggling the modal to display?

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

or

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is `e.preventDefault()`